# XMPP TLS connection with SslStream

Tags: c#, xmpp, ssl, sslstream

I am trying to create a simple xmpp client that connects to Gtalk. 
The first part of the handshake seems to work.
Ror the TLS handshake I created a client SslStream, connected to the intended server (talk.google.com) and successfully got authenticated .

The first SSlStream.Read is to receive the greeting reply, it went fine . I do a SslStream.write to send my first command, but when i do my Sslstream.Read() to get the reply , i get this error."System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine."

Can anyone point me to the right direction?

I am using code very similar to the example on msdn http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream.aspx
except that I switch from a Network stream to a Sslstream when TLS is negotiated.

```
 netStream.Flush(); 
 sslStream = new SslStream(netStream,               
               true,
               new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate),
               null
               );

  sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient("talk.google.com");
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd try using one of the existing XMPP libraries for .Net:

- Jabber-Net: http://code.google.com/p/jabber-net/
- agsXMPP: http://www.ag-software.de/agsxmpp-sdk/

Even if you don't use of these libs, you'll get some good ideas from looking at the code.

In this case, you probably want:

```
sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient("gmail.com");
```

where `gmail.com` is the domain name from the JID you're trying to log in as.

Comment: I had a look at those libraries. Im trying to build one from scratch as an exercise, as I want to learn more about xmpp. I have tried gmail.com already but it has the same problem.

Comment: I think my problem is with how I am using the ssl stream rather than the server.